# SwiftUI : How I can delete the UIimage in the View saved as Codable?

Tags: list, swiftui, uiimage, crud

I tried to save the image in my memo with as UIImage as Codable protocol.

My code can be a little bit longer, but please refer to it.

**1. first one is the NewMemoView that I can make my memo with ImagePicker.**

```
import SwiftUI

struct NewMemoView: View {
    
    let folder : FolderModel
    let memo : MemoModel?
    
    @State private var items : [Any] = []
    
    @EnvironmentObject var vm : MemoViewModel
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    
    @State private var title : String = ""
    @State private var content : String = ""
    @State private var color : Color = .mint
    @State private var showAlert : Bool = false
    @State private var pickedImportance : String = "Anytime "
    @State private var isEditMode : Bool = false
    @State private var isSecret : Bool = false
    @State private var password : String = ""
    @State private var showShareSheet : Bool = false
    @State private var showImagePicker : Bool = false
    @State private var selectedImage : UIImage?
    @State private var tappedImage : Bool = false
    @State private var showDeleteImageOption : Bool = false
    
    let importances = ["Anytime ", "Normal ☀️", "Important "]
    
    var someImage : SomeImage? {
        guard let image = selectedImage else {return nil}
        return SomeImage(image: image)
    }
    
    init(memo : MemoModel?, folder : FolderModel) {
        self.folder = folder
        self.memo = memo
        if let memo = memo {
            _title = State(initialValue: memo.title)
            _content = State(initialValue: memo.content)
            _color = State(initialValue: memo.color)
            _pickedImportance = State(initialValue: memo.isImportant)
            _isEditMode = State(initialValue: true)
            _isSecret = State(initialValue: memo.isSecret)
            _password = State(initialValue: memo.password ?? "")
            _selectedImage = State(initialValue: memo.image?.image)
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            Section(header : Text("Title ")) {
                TextField("Input the title", text: $title)
                    .autocapitalization(.none)
                    .disableAutocorrection(true)
            }
            
            Section(header : Text("Importance ✅")) {
                Picker("", selection: $pickedImportance) {
                    ForEach(importances, id: \.self) {
                        Text($0)
                    }
                }
                .pickerStyle(.segmented)
            }
            
            Section(header : Text("Content ✏️(총 \(content.count) 자)")) {
                TextEditor(text: $content)
                    .autocapitalization(.none)
                    .disableAutocorrection(true)
                    .frame(maxWidth : .infinity)
                    .frame(height : UIScreen.main.bounds.height * 0.25)

            }
            
            .onTapGesture {
                UIApplication.shared.closeKeyboard()
            }
            
            Section(header : Text("Image List ")) {
                HStack {
                    if let selectedImage = selectedImage {
                        Image(uiImage: selectedImage)
                            .resizable()
                            .scaledToFill()
                            .frame(width : 50, height : 50)
                            .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 12))
                            .onTapGesture {
                                tappedImage.toggle()
                            }
                            .onLongPressGesture(perform: {
                                showDeleteImageOption.toggle()
                            })
                            .confirmationDialog(Text("Delete Image"), isPresented: $showDeleteImageOption, actions: {
                                Button(role : .destructive, action: {
                                    vm.deleteImage(folder: folder, memo: memo!, title: title, content: content, color: color, isImportant: pickedImportance, isSecret: isSecret, password: password)
                                }, label: {
                                    Text("Delete Image")
                                })
                            })
                            .sheet(isPresented: $tappedImage) {
                                ImageView(image: self.selectedImage!)
                            }
                    } else {
                        Text("You can upload only 'one' Image")
                            .foregroundColor(.gray)
                    }
                }
                .padding(8)
            }
            
            Section(header : Text("Memo Settings ⚙️")) {
                ColorPicker("Memo Color", selection: $color, supportsOpacity: false)
                Toggle(isOn: $isSecret, label: {
                    Text("Enable Secret Mode")
                })
                
                if isSecret {
                    HStack {
                        Text("Password : ")
                        Spacer()
                        TextField("Input", text: $password)
                    }
                }
            }
            
            Button(action: {   
                if isEditMode {
                    if let someImage = someImage {
                        if vm.checkMemoStatus(title: title, content: content) {
                            vm.editMemo(folder: folder, memo: memo!, title: title, content: content, color: color, isImportant: pickedImportance, isSecret: isSecret, password: password, image : someImage)
                            presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                        } else {
                            vm.editMemo(folder: folder, memo: memo!, title: title, content: content, color: color, isImportant: pickedImportance, isSecret: isSecret, password: password, image : nil)
                            presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                        }
                    } else {
                        self.showAlert.toggle()
                    }
                } else {
                    if vm.checkMemoStatus(title: title, content: content) {
                        if let someImage = someImage {
                            vm.addMemo(folder: folder, title: title, content: content, color: color, isImportant: pickedImportance, isSecret: isSecret, password: password, image: someImage)
                            presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                        } else {
                            vm.addMemo(folder: folder, title: title, content: content, color: color, isImportant: pickedImportance, isSecret: isSecret, password: password, image: nil)
                            presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                        }
                    } else {
                        self.showAlert.toggle()
                    }
                }
            }, label: {
                Text(isEditMode ? "Edit".uppercased() : "save".uppercased())
                    .fontWeight(.bold)
            })
            .alert(isPresented : $showAlert) {
                Alert(title: Text("Warning "), message: Text("Check your title and content, please."), dismissButton: .cancel())
            }
        }//form
        .navigationTitle("Add Memo ")
        .toolbar {
            ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                Button(action: {
                    share()
                }, label: {
                    Image(systemName: "square.and.arrow.up")
                })
                .disabled(!isEditMode)
            }
            ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                Button(action: {
                    showImagePicker.toggle()
                }, label: {
                    Image(systemName: "photo")
                })
                .sheet(isPresented: $showImagePicker) {
                    ImagePicker(image: $selectedImage)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

extension NewMemoView {
    func share() {
        let content = memo?.content
        let image = memo?.image?.image
        let vc = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [image, content], applicationActivities: nil)
        UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.rootViewController?.present(vc, animated: true)
    }
}
```

**2. Second one is the viewModel for memos.**

```
import SwiftUI
import Foundation

class MemoViewModel : ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var sortedMode : SortedMode?
    @Published var folders : [FolderModel] = [] {
        didSet {
            saveData()
        }
    }
    
    init() {
        getData()
    }
    
    let foldersKey = "Folders_key"
    
    func saveData() {
        if let encodedData = try? JSONEncoder().encode(folders) {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(encodedData, forKey: foldersKey)
        }
    }
    
    func getData() {
        guard let data = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: foldersKey),
              let savedData = try? JSONDecoder().decode([FolderModel].self, from: data)
        else {return}
        self.folders = savedData
    }
    
    func addNewFolder(folderName : String) {
        let newFolder = FolderModel(folderName: folderName)
        folders.append(newFolder)
    }
    
    func deleteFolder(folder : FolderModel) {
        if let index = folders.firstIndex(where: {$0.id == folder.id}) {
            folders.remove(at: index)
        }
    }
    
    func deleteFolder(indexSet : IndexSet) {
        folders.remove(atOffsets: indexSet)
    }
    
    func checkFolderNameCount(folderName : String) -> Bool {
        if folderName.count < 3 {
            return false
        } else {
            return true
        }
    }
    
    func checkMemoStatus(title : String, content : String) -> Bool {
        if title.count == 0 || content.count == 0 {
            return false
        } else {
            return true
        }
    }
    
    func addMemo(folder : FolderModel, title : String, content : String, color : Color, isImportant : String, isSecret : Bool, password : String, image : SomeImage?) {
        if let index = folders.firstIndex(where: {$0.id == folder.id}) {
            let newMemo = MemoModel(title : title, content : content, color : color, isImportant: isImportant, isSecret: isSecret, password: password, image: image)
            folders[index].memo.append(newMemo)
        }
    }
    
    func editMemo(folder : FolderModel, memo : MemoModel, title : String, content : String, color : Color, isImportant : String, isSecret : Bool, password : String, image : SomeImage?) {
        if let index = folders.firstIndex(where: {$0.id == folder.id}) {
            if let index1 = folders[index].memo.firstIndex(where: {$0.id == memo.id}) {
                folders[index].memo[index1] = memo.editMemo(title: title, content: content, color: color, isImportant: isImportant, isSecret: isSecret, password: password, image : image)
            }
        }
    }
    
    func deleteMemo(folder : FolderModel, memo : MemoModel) {
        if let index = folders.firstIndex(where: {$0.id == folder.id}) {
            if let index1 = folders[index].memo.firstIndex(where: {$0.id == memo.id}) {
                folders[index].memo.remove(at: index1)
            }
        }
    }
    
    func deleteImage(folder : FolderModel, memo : MemoModel, title : String, content : String, color : Color, isImportant : String, isSecret : Bool, password : String) {
        if let index = folders.firstIndex(where: {$0.id == folder.id}) {
            if let index1 = folders[index].memo.firstIndex(where: {$0.id == memo.id}) {
                folders[index].memo[index1] = memo.deleteImage(title: title, content: content, color: color, isImportant: isImportant, isSecret: isSecret, password: password)
            }
        }
    }
    
    func checkPassword(memo : MemoModel, password : String) -> Bool {
        if memo.password == password {
            return true
        } else {
            return false
        }
    }
    
    func sortedMemos(folder : FolderModel) {
        if let sortedMode = sortedMode {
            switch sortedMode {
            case .moreImportant:
                if let index = folders.firstIndex(where: {$0.id == folder.id}) {
                    folders[index].memo.sort(by: {$0.isImportant > $1.isImportant})
                }
            case .faster:
                if let index = folders.firstIndex(where: {$0.id == folder.id}) {
                    folders[index].memo.sort(by: {$0.timeStamp < $1.timeStamp})
                }
            case .later:
                if let index = folders.firstIndex(where: {$0.id == folder.id}) {
                    folders[index].memo.sort(by: {$0.timeStamp > $1.timeStamp})
                }
            case .lessImportant:
                if let index = folders.firstIndex(where: {$0.id == folder.id}) {
                    folders[index].memo.sort(by: {$0.isImportant > $1.isImportant})
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

enum SortedMode {
    case moreImportant, faster, later, lessImportant
}
```

**3. Last one is the codable model for this memo App**

```
import SwiftUI
import Foundation

struct FolderModel : Identifiable, Codable {
    var id = UUID()
    var folderName : String
    var memo : [MemoModel] = []
}

struct MemoModel : Identifiable, Codable {
    var id = UUID()
    var title : String = "제목 없음"
    var content : String
    var color : Color = .gray
    var timeStamp : String = Date().formatted(date: .numeric, time: .omitted)
    var isImportant : String
    var isSecret : Bool = false
    var password : String?
    var image : SomeImage?

    func editMemo(title : String, content : String, color : Color, isImportant : String, isSecret : Bool, password : String, image : SomeImage?) -> MemoModel {
        return MemoModel(id: id, title: title, content: content, color: color, isImportant: isImportant, isSecret: isSecret, password: password, image: image)
    }
    
    func deleteImage(title : String, content : String, color : Color, isImportant : String, isSecret : Bool, password : String) -> MemoModel {
        return MemoModel(id: id, title: title, content: content, color: color, isImportant: isImportant, isSecret: isSecret, password: password, image: nil)
    }
}

struct SomeImage : Identifiable, Codable {
    var id = UUID()
    var image: UIImage?

    init(image: UIImage) {
        self.image = image
    }

    enum CodingKeys: CodingKey {
        case data
        case scale
    }

    public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        let scale = try container.decode(CGFloat.self, forKey: .scale)
        let data = try container.decode(Data.self, forKey: .data)
        self.image = UIImage(data: data, scale: scale)
    }

    public func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        if let image = self.image {
            try container.encode(image.pngData(), forKey: .data)
            try container.encode(image.scale, forKey: .scale)
        }
    }
}
```

I will summarize my point!

1. When I try to delete the image by deleteMemo, giving nil to image, the NewMemoView is shut down. I don't know why, but it it doing.
2. When I tap the save button with image, there is some lagging, how I can handle this situation? I think maybe that most of image has bigger capacity than text.

Thanks!

Comment: UserDefault is not a good place for big data, at least your image should be kept outside (library/document directory for example) and only keep relative file name in coded data. You may more easily use files/folders or a database for your need. The time it take to save one image or delete it is the time user to update full UserDefault file which will become bigger over time.

Comment: @PtitXav Thanks! so, If I use Filemanager on that, is that good choice?

Comment: File manager is good choice for images.